# Reach static files in Blazor WebAssembly app outside of the wwwroot

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly app and I would like to reach some static files outside of the wwwroot (these are some outputs to download). One solution would be a symlink from wwwroot to that folder, but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

For the Server app of a hosted Blazor WebAssembly solution,
You could try call staticfile middleware as below:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "your folder")),
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that was my idee too, did not work! Important: "yout folder" is something like "c:\AnyDir"

Comment: ContentRootPath should be  absolute path to the directory that contains the application content files. If you  want to reach some static files in another floder outside of the wwwroot ,just relace "your folder" with the name of your folder

Comment: Also, call app.UseStaticFiles() again for the static files in wwwroot or try with a CompositeFileProvider as the document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-from-multiple-locations

Comment: If you still have problems,please provide a minimal example that could repo

Comment: I wanted to reach them from the hosted WebAsm app, not from the server app, but I think it makes no sense, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have correctly configured the StaticFiles provider, remove '~/' in the path. This was fixed on my end.

Before: '~/images/product/test.png'
Working: 'images/product/test.png'

I'm working with Blazor WebAssembly app.